# How to show: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}P(X=k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}P(X=k)$

Tags: probability-theory, summation

Can anyone explain why this equation is true.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}P(X=k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}P(X=k).$$

Comment: Both are sums over pairs $(k,n)$ with $1\leq n\leq k$ of the same expression. Since $P(X=k)\geq 0$, if either side is convergent, you can rearrange the sums freely.

Comment: Okay, so it's Tonnellis Theorem which is applied ?

Comment: @New_to_this: Yes, you can interpret it this way.

Comment: Tonelli's theorem certain can be cited here.  So can Fubini's theorem.  Fubini's theorem applies in the case when the sum of all absolute values of the terms is finite.  Tonelli's theorem applies when all terms are non-negative, regardless of whether their sum is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_{k,n}=P(X=k)$ if $k\geq n$ and $a_{k,n}=0$ otherwise. Then we need to show:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^k P(X=k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{k,n}\stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k,n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_{k,n}$$

That interior switch is, as you say, a result of [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) for summations, since $a_{k,n}\geq 0$.

Comment: This was my final conclusion aswell. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted answers to this here before.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^k P(X=k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty P(X=k).$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccccccccc}
& n=1 & n=2 & n=3 & n=4 & \cdots
\\
\hline
k=1 & \bullet \\
k=2 & \bullet & \bullet \\
k=3 & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
k=4 & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}
$$
The sum $\sum_{n=1}^k$ goes along the $k$th **horizontal** row (and is a finite sum).

The sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^k$ then adds those up.

The sum $\sum_{k=n}^\infty$ goes down the $n$th **vertical column** (and is thus an infinite sum, and starts at $n$, not at $0$).

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty$ then adds those up.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you can swap the sums, of course. The key is that $P(X=k)\geq 0$.